# How to get domain of caller SIP account with PHPAGI?

Tags: asterisk

I would like to write AGI script for Asterisk with PHPAGI which do following:
+ Check caller is SIP account or not.
+ If caller is SIP, hangup and redial to caller

The problem I have is that I can only get caller SIP user by following code:

```
$ret = $agi->parse_callerid();
$domain = $ret['host'];
$user = $ret['username'];
```

$user has correct value but $domain is always empty.

How can I get domain of caller SIP account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using some trick:

```
$user = $agi->request['agi_callerid'];
$domain = $agi->request['agi_channel'];
$domain = substr($domain, 4);
$pos = strrpos($domain, '-');
$domain = substr($domain, 0, $pos);
```

Comment: Note: this will not always give you correct answer.